# Avoiding workload overlap with parallelized services

Tags: node.js, database, parallel-processing, docker-swarm

A worker service fetches pending jobs from a database, and processes them one by one. The natural way to speed this up would be to spawn multiple (arbitrary amount) instances of the worker service (via Docker swarm or similar), and have them all simultaneously process pending jobs.

How would you ensure that two instances of the worker do not process the same job?

I have thought about using a central, non-parallelized manager service which keeps track of the workers and sends jobs to them, instead of the workers fetching their own jobs, but I imagine a time will come where the manager service itself will need to be parallelized. This solution seems just to kick the problem a bit further into the future.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How would you **ensure** that two instances of the worker do not process the same job?"*

Simple :
**a )** monopolise the access-methods not to be freely accessible, the less from any Worker(s), plus...
**b )** let only the Job-Dispatcher execute this Job-2-Worker mapping, plus...
**c )** set the Job-Dispatcher scaling to be workload adaptive ( adding more power under higher load ), plus...
**d )** let the Job-Dispatcher survive some mix of co-located / distributed failures ( yes, best as a distributed multi-agent, self-resilient entity )

And you are done :
Now you have a safe, right-sized, adaptively scalable, robust & DDoS-proof intelligent system.